# Library for Exchange ActiveSync (EAS) protocol on Android

Tags: android, exchange-server

I am trying to get all canlendar info with Exchange ActiveSync protocol from server on Android. But I can not find any library for this. Is there a library for EAS protocol on Android?

Thanks a lot.